# How do I replicate CSPlib's Latex logo?

Tags: fonts, formatting

In the [CSPLib](http://www.csplib.org/) paper, they use a special kind of formatting for their logo. What is the best way of replicating that logo?

Comment: Probably by using the GIF that's in the site (converted to PNG), assuming it's allowed using it.

Comment: Could you specify what logo you're referring to?  All I found looked like `CSP\textsc{lib}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In their manual it’s just small caps

```
CSP\textsc{lib}
```

You may want to make a command to use it. Add `\xspace` to get the right space after your command automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand\CSPLIB{CSP\textsc{lib}\xspace}

\begin{document}
Try using the \CSPLIB now.
\end{document}
```

[image: CSPlib]